# Error 1452 - Foreign key constraint fails

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

These are two of the MySQL tables:

```
CREATE TABLE LPC.ChildInformation
(
    ChildID CHAR(4),
    FirstName TEXT,
    Surname TEXT,
    Gender TEXT,
    DateOfBirth DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (ChildID)
);

CREATE TABLE LPC.ChildAttendance
(
    ChildID CHAR(4),
    DateAttended DATE,
    TypeOfDay VARCHAR(15),
    TypeOfTime VARCHAR(15),
    PlannedArrivalTime TIME,
    PlannedDepartureTime TIME,
    ActualArrivalTime TIME,
    ActualDepartureTime TIME,
    PRIMARY KEY (ChildID, DateAttended),
    FOREIGN KEY (ChildID) REFERENCES ChildInformation(ChildID)
);
```

The following query executes without any issues:

```
USE LPC;
INSERT INTO ChildInformation(ChildID, FirstName, Surname, Gender, DateOfBirth)
VALUES('C002', 'Shanaya', 'Talang', 'Female', '2010/02/03');
```

However, this query doesn't:

```
USE LPC;
INSERT INTO ChildAttendance(ChildID, DateAttended, TypeOfDay, TypeOfTime, PlannedArrivalTime, PlannedDepartureTime, ActualArrivalTime, ActualDepartureTime)
VALUES ('C002','2015/01/26', 'Weekday', 'AfterSchool', '15:40:00', '17:30:00', '15:40:00', '17:47:00');
```

The following error message comes up:
Error Code: 1452. Cannot add or update a child row; a foreign key constraint fails...

I have looked elsewhere for advice but found nothing that helps me. Any helpful advice is very much appreciated as I need this solving as soon as possible. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be nothing else than a typo: The child you inserted into `ChildInformation` has a `ChildID` of "C001", but the row you insert into `ChildAttendance` references a `ChildID` of "C002".

Since you explicitly define a constraint, that rows in `ChildAttendance` must reference an existing row in `ChildInformation`, this is invalid and is rejected **as designed**.

Comment: Sorry about that - I accidentally typed it wrong-and have now edited it. The ChildID is actually "C002" instead of "C001". Do you know what else the error could be because of?

Comment: With the correct `ChildID` this works as expected: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/202d75/1/0